# SOAP Webservices XML case sensitivity

Tags: c#, soap

I'm creating a SOAP WebServices

I created one classe used for serialization and deserialization

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ELEMENTS")]
    public class Elements
    {
        [XmlAttribute("FIRSTELEMENT")]
        public string FirstElement { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("SECONDELEMENT")]
        public string SecondElement { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a Controller with on method

```
    public class UpperCaseController : ApiController
    {
        public string FirstCall(Elements data)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

When I launch my webservice and I go thru chrome in the API definition I have :

> application/xml, text/xml
>   Sample:

```
<Elements xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestWS.Models">
  <FirstElement>sample string 1</FirstElement>
  <SecondElement>sample string 2</SecondElement>
</Elements>
```

I need to have the Element in upper like defined in the XmlAttribute(ElementName).
How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since xml tags are case sensetive, it means that there could be a variation of the same word but it would be considered two different tags.
 and  are two different tags.

If you want to go the route where you dont care about any case sensetivity, you can do that by converting everything to uppercase before deserializing the xml. once you have the string in uppercase, deserialize it and then do away with the values. NOTE: You will have everything in the values in uppercase as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found the issue.

I had to add in the WebApiConfig the line :

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Now it works.